# How can I add another importable root-level directory to my NX workspace

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-workspace

I would like to add another directory like `libs` in the root of my project form which apps can import. In my case, I have a set of microservices in a `functions` directory and I would like one of my apps to import the interfaces directly from this directory rather than create yet another lib just to hold the sharable interfaces.

(Trust me, I've thought this decision through)

[image]

how can I modify my boundary rules to permit imports for this directory?

```
    "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
      "error",
      {
        "enforceBuildableLibDependency": true,
        "allow": [],
        "depConstraints": [
          {
            "sourceTag": "*",
            "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["*"]
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: I was hopeful to get here and find the answer. :(

Comment: I just gave up and made a dedicated lib for shared resources. Honestly, it's the "correct" way to do it wrt convention.